# 301 https reverse proxy squid redirection for reply headers

Tags: squid

It is a silly question but can someone explain in detail this part of this code ? :

```
301:https:
```

in this little section:

```
$| = 1; 
while (<>) {
     s/^http:/301:https:/;
     print;
}
```

This is used for rewriting http to https in squid i just don't understand why is that code 301 in front is it necessary ? Why is 301 Perm-moved used here?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Just the right thing for my very first answer. As [the HTTP protocol definition](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) says:

> 301 Moved Permanently
>
> The requested resource has been assigned a **new permanent URI** and any
> future references to this resource SHOULD use one of the **returned
> URIs**.

as opposed to

> 302 Found
>
> The requested resource resides **temporarily** under a different URI.
> Since the redirection might be altered on occasion, the client SHOULD
> continue to **use the Request-URI for future requests**.

So your code snippet will advise clients to stop using http and start using https instead. This is mainly relevant for search bots and other crawlers, I dont think Browsers are smart enough to automatically alter bookmarks that changed like this.
And references on other websites, added by their authors manually, will not change either.

If a 302 was returned in your code snippet, automated bots would keep hitting http, expecting the site to work again under http in the future.